# Is there any way to attract or push away a proton?

Tags: electrons, atoms, protons

Like an electron that can be attracted by positive charge (or less negative charge), is there any way to make a proton move by attraction?

Comment: What does a proton do in an electric field? A moving proton in a magnetic field? What exactly *are* you asking?

Comment: Happens all the time. They just have to be in a fluid environment rather than bound in a macroscopic solid.

Comment: A cute electron in a skimpy dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protons will move in the opposite direction from electrons in electric or magnetic fields.

The only issue is that unattached electrons are easier to generate than protons. But, once you've done that, say by ionising hydrogen in a vacuum tube (which creates protons and electrons), any electric or magnetic fields will make both of them move, in opposite directions.

The deflection or speed of the proton will not be as large as that of electrons, because it is almost 2000 times more massive, but the same electromagnetic laws apply to both.